# How to quickly select items from the list that correspond to elements of the array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want display on page only facebook url, twitter url. In Table links about 40 urls for different messegers, social networks.

My code:

```
<ul class="icons-bar icons-bar_socials icons-bar_socials_profile">
 <% @freelancer.links.each do |link| %>
   <% if link.messenger_type.title == "facebook" %>       
      <li class="icons-bar__item">
         <%= link_to link.url, link.url, class: "icons-bar__icon icon_faceebook" %>
   </li>
   <% end %>
   <% if link.messenger_type.title == "twitter" %>       
      <li class="icons-bar__item">
         <%= link_to link.url, link.url, class: "icons-bar__icon icon_twitter" %>
   </li>  
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

list.rb

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: links
#
#  id                :integer          not null, primary key
#  url               :string
#  freelancer_id     :integer
#  messenger_type_id :integer
#
# Indexes
#
#  index_links_on_freelancer_id      (freelancer_id)
#  index_links_on_messenger_type_id  (messenger_type_id)
#

class Link < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :freelancer
    belongs_to :messenger_type

end
```

**messenger_type.rb**

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: messenger_types
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  title      :string
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#

class MessengerType < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :links
end
```

I do not like this the way. What is there a more elegant way to implement this task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is more clear and also remove unnecessary conditionals.

You can also put it in a helper if you want.

```
<ul class="icons-bar icons-bar_socials icons-bar_socials_profile">
  <% @freelancer.links.select{|link| ["twitter", "facebook"].include? link.messager_type.title  }.each do |link| %>      
      <li class="icons-bar__item">
        <%= link_to link.url, link.url, class: "icons-bar__icon icon_#{link.messager_type.title}" %>
      </li>
  <%end%>         
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

This would be more elegant:

```
<ul class="icons-bar icons-bar_socials icons-bar_socials_profile">   
<% if ['twitter', 'facebook'].include? link.messenger_type.title %>       
      <li class="icons-bar__item">
         <%= link_to link.url, link.url, class: "icons-bar__icon icon_#{link.messenger_type.title.downcase}" %>
   </li>  
  <% end %>
 </ul>
```

EDIT: of course should have added the ul tag